# No Entity Framework, os métodos SingleOrDefault() e FirstOrDefault() apresentam comportamentos diferentes?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Qual são as diferenças entre `SingleOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault()`, e quando usar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[***SingleOrDefault***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) retorna o único elemento de uma sequência, ou um valor padrão se a sequência está vazia; este método gera uma exceção se houver mais de um elemento na sequência. (*MSDN, Método Enumerable.SingleOrDefault (IEnumerable), 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Data de acesso. 08.jun.2014*). Ou seja, se na consulta tiver apenas um registro pode ser utilizado sem problemas, mas mais que um registro ele retorna uma exceção igual a imagem logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ser utilizado para campos chave primárias (`Primary Key`) sem problemas, e se não tiver nenhum registro, o método retornar o valor padrão do tipo informado.

[***FirstOrDefault***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) retorna o primeiro elemento de uma sequência, ou um valor padrão se a sequência não contiver elementos(MSDN, Método Enumerable.FirstOrDefault (IEnumerable), 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Data de acesso: 08.jun.2014). Não tem o mesmo problema do  [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), ele busca o primeiro elemento em vários encontrados, não emitindo erros.

Existem também a diferença entre esses dois métodos na sua geração de *SQL*: O [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) faz um `Select Top(2)`, enquanto, o [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) faz um `Select Top(1)`.

**Conclusão:**

Se pretende trazer apenas um registro ou testar a ocorrência de mais itens com uma exceção utilize [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), se não utilize [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), para que traga a primeira ocorrência ou então o valor padrão (*default*).

*Referências:*

- [Método Enumerable.SingleOrDefault (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Método Enumerable.FirstOrDefault (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)