# Como atualizar um item de uma lista genérica?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, genéricos

Estou tentando alterar o nome e e-mail de um determinado item da lista abaixo, mas não encontrei outra forma além de remover o item da lista e adicioná-lo novamente atualizado. Existe outra forma de atualizar?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Aluno> aluno = new List<Aluno>{
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 1, Nome = "Cláudia",Email="claudia@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 2, Nome = "Pedro",Email="pedro@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 3, Nome = "Eduardo",Email="eduardo@email.com" }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("==================================");

        foreach (var item in aluno)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNome: {1}\nEmail: {2}", item.AlunoId, item.Nome,item.Email);
            Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Aluno
{
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo. Sabe como atualizar *array*? É a mesma coisa:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var aluno = new List<Aluno> {
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 1, Nome = "Cláudia",Email="claudia@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 2, Nome = "Pedro",Email="pedro@email.com" },
            new Aluno() { AlunoId = 3, Nome = "Eduardo",Email="eduardo@email.com" }
        };
        WriteLine("==================================");
        foreach (var item in aluno) {
            WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNome: {1}\nEmail: {2}", item.AlunoId, item.Nome,item.Email);
            WriteLine("==================================");
        }
        aluno[0].Nome = "João";
        aluno[0].Email = "joao@email.com";
        foreach (var item in aluno) {
            WriteLine("ID: {0}\nNome: {1}\nEmail: {2}", item.AlunoId, item.Nome,item.Email);
            WriteLine("==================================");
        }
    }
}

class Aluno {
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5CXhsz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQobey). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/GenericList.cs).

Aí está alterando o primeiro item, mas pode alterar qualquer quiser, pode ser através de uma variável no índice ou mesmo fazer uma busca em algum elemento. Existem até métodos prontos para isto, mas já é outro assunto.

Answer (score 6):

Para alterar os dados do **primeiro aluno** na lista, você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
aluno[0].Nome = "NovoNome";
aluno[0].Email = "email@aluno.com";
```

Para alterar outras posições, você apenas precisa trocar o **0** pelo **index** da posição que deseja alterar.

Obs.: Sempre que for acessar uma posição de uma `array`,`List` ou `IEnumerable` e afins a contagem começa pelo **index 0**. Logo, se sua `Collection` tiver **10** posições, o último index será **9**.

---

Além de poder os *indexes* para localizar o item que deseja alterar na lista, você pode incluir (`using`) o `namespace` `System.Linq` e fazer consultas (bem parecidas com sql) dentro da sua lista. Como, por exemplo, para buscar o aluno com nome **João**:

```
var joao = aluno.Single(x => x.Nome == "João");
//ou
var joao = aluno.First(x => x.Nome == "João");
```

O `Single()` e o `First()` fazem praticamente a mesma coisa, eles devolvem apenas um registro que atenda a condição. Porém, quando há mais de um registro que atenda a condição o `Single()` lança uma `exception` e o `First()` retorna a primeira que encontrar. Você pode ver sobre isso na publicação: [No Entity Framework, os métodos SingleOrDefault() e FirstOrDefault() apresentam comportamentos diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20560/18246)

---

Além dos métodos supra citados, existem os métodos `FirstOrDefault()` e `SingleOrDefault()`. Eles têm comportamentos parecidos com `First()` e `Single`, com a única diferença de que não estouram `exception` se nenhum item atender a condição, mas retornam `null`.

O uso é exatamente igual:

```
var joao = aluno.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Nome == "João");
//ou
var joao = aluno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nome == "João");
```