# Qual a melhor solução ? GetById com id não existente no BD

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou fazendo uma chamada no meu repository mas nem sempre o CPF existe no BD. Quando não existe no banco de dados recebo o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Repository**

```
public VendedorModel GetById(int CPF)
    {
        using (var db = new PowerVendasEntities())
        {
            var registro = db.Vendedor.Single(x => x.VendedorCPF == CPF);

            return VendedorFactory.ToModel(registro);
        }
    }
```

Qual a melhor forma de solucionar este problema ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [No Entity Framework, os métodos SingleOrDefault() e FirstOrDefault() apresentam comportamentos diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20560/no-entity-framework-os-m%c3%a9todos-singleordefault-e-firstordefault-apresentam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) ou  o [SingleOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés de Single().

**FirstOrDefault():**

> Retorna o primeiro elemento de uma sequência, ou um valor padrão se a
>   sequência não contiver elementos.

**SingleOrDefault()**

> Retorna o único elemento de uma sequência ou um valor padrão se a
>   sequência é vazia; esse método gera uma exceção se há mais de um
>   elemento na sequência.

**Como ficaria:**

```
public VendedorModel GetById(int CPF)
    {
        using (var db = new PowerVendasEntities())
        {
            var registro = db.Vendedor.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VendedorCPF == CPF);

            return VendedorFactory.ToModel(registro);
        }
    }
```

Comment: mas ai não consigo fazer o "return VendedorFactory.ToModel" pq registro vai ser null. Alguma alternativa ?

Comment: @carloshenriqueribeiro Retornar `null` =D

Comment: Colocando uma condicional ? pq o parâmetro pode ser um CPF válido e encontrado na base, neste caso tem que retornar a model mesmo.

Comment: Não entendi muito o que você quis dizer, mas como o LINQ disse você pode  retornar null e tratar isso aonde você chamou essa função (GetById(CPF)), informando  para o usuario que o CPF nao existe no banco.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
public VendedorModel GetById(int CPF){
    using (var db = new PowerVendasEntities()){
         var registro = db.Vendedor.SingleOrDefault(x => x.VendedorCPF == CPF);
         return registro != null ? VendedorFactory.ToModel(registro) : null;
    }
}
```

Apenas complementando o que já foi bem explicado na resposta aceita sobre o `SingleOrDefault()`, neste caso se o Banco não encontrar nenhum Vendedor com este CPF, retornará um `null`, utilizando um [Operador Ternário](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1):

O problema de usar o [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679577(v=vs.90).aspx) é que ele lança para o banco de dados um [Top 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11841871/2740371), e caso existar dois registros para o filtro passado ele retorna um erro e caso nenhum registro seja encontrado ele também retorna um erro, ou seja, ele espera que apenas um registro seja encontrado na base de dados.

Isso é um problema pois causa perda de performance, fora que ainda tem que ser tratado na aplicação os erros.

A solução indicada é usar os métodos; [First ou FirstOrDefault](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx). 
Você pode até usar o [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679607(v=vs.90).aspx), mas ainda estaria mandando um TOP 2 para a base e caso exista mais de um registro ele ainda retorna um erro.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção de solução também pode ser esta:

```
public VendedorModel GetById(int CPF)
{
    using (var db = new PowerVendasEntities())
    {
        var registro = db.Vendedor
            .Where(x => x.VendedorCPF == CPF)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return VendedorFactory.ToModel(registro);
    }
}
```